# Can't log in after partition recovery

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and accidentally deleted all partitions. I then used testdisk to retrieve one of the partitions, and after it finished it needed a reboot. I rebooted and now I can't unlock the disk. In the initial screen with the Ubuntu logo and "Enter passphrase:" I enter the password which I'm 100% sure it's correct and it says "cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?"
I pressed ESC and got a black screen that says "requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/disk/by-uuid/22d81ad4-83d8-492c-9514-09015088a3cf."

I started Ubuntu from the bootable USB, chose to try without installation, and I found that one of the partitions is back and there's a lock 250 MB partition that won't unlock although I only used one password and I'm sure it's correct.

How can I unlock the pc? I'm using an HP ProBook 450.

Comment: I'd have used testdisk to retrieve all of the partitions, if that were possible... Is there an "empty" partition where the old LUKS partition (I'm assuming) used to be? Some programs that create blank partitions may try to "erase" any old filesystems on the disk where the new partition will be - that would be bad.

Comment: I've just had this same issue on three separate Ubuntu PCs over the last week! Really interested in knowing what's going on...